# Why do we always talk only about length contraction in the longitudinal direction and not contraction in other transversal dimensions?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, observers

why do we always talk only about length contraction and not contraction in other dimensions? if spacetime is uniform in all directions then change in one dimension must lead to a change in other dimensions right?

Comment: If spacetime is uniform in all directions, then whenever you move forward you must also move leftward, right?

Comment: I'm not too conversant in special relativity so I will be interested in the answers you get. It seems to me that if length contraction is real it should be accompanied by extension of the other dimensions. But I don't know.

Comment: While the answer to your question is given below, once I have asked in a comment if a kind of balloon inflating at speed about c can be seen as shrinking :) Perhaps i shall ask...

Comment: @bobd have a look at the answer I've added, which I hope will address your issue.

Answer (score 4):

I shall simply reproduce the relevant section from *Introduction to Electrodynamics*, 4th ed. by Griffiths.

> A moving object is shortened *only along the direction of its motion*:
>
> **Dimensions perpendicular to the velocity are not contracted.**
>
> Indeed, in deriving the time dilation formula I took it for granted that the *height* of the train is the same for both observers. I’ll now justify this, using a lovely gedanken experiment suggested by Taylor and Wheeler.<sup>8</sup>
>
> Imagine that we build a wall beside the railroad tracks, and $1~\mathrm{m}$ above the rails (*as measured on the ground*), we paint a horizontal blue line. When the train goes by, a passenger leans out the window holding a wet paintbrush $1~\mathrm{m}$ above the rails, *as measured on the train*, leaving a horizontal red line on the wall. *Question*: Does the passenger’s red
> line lie above or below our blue one? If the rule were that perpendicular directions contract, then the person on the ground would predict that the *red* line is lower, while the person on the train would say it’s the *blue* one (to the latter, of course, the *ground* is moving). The principle of relativity says that both observers are equally justified, but they cannot both be right. No subtleties of simultaneity or synchronization can rationalize this contradiction; either the blue line is higher or
> the red one is—*unless they exactly coincide*, which is the inescapable conclusion. There *cannot* be a law of contraction (or expansion) of perpendicular dimensions, for it would lead to irreconcilably inconsistent predictions.
>
> <sub><sup>8</sup>E. F. Taylor and J. A. Wheeler, Spacetime Physics 2nd ed. (San Francisco: W. H. Freeman, 1992).
> A somewhat different version of the same argument is given in J. H. Smith, Introduction to special relativity (Champaign, IL: Stipes, 1965).</sub>

Comment: I don't know much about SR. But I do know that contraction does not occur perpendicular to the velocity. But if the contraction is physically real, why doesn't it result in extension or expansion perpendicular to the velocity, like what happens when an object is subjected to axial compressive loading?

Comment: @BobD I confess that I don't know the answer to your question. Perhaps asking a new question would help.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I'll wait to see if any of the others can answer it.

Comment: @Bob D I think you're being misled by the phrase 'Physically real'. When people use this phrase about length contraction they don't mean that the contraction is identical in itself and in its consequences to the sort of contraction that you get when you put a rod under compressive stress along its long axis. They mean that perfectly rigorous length measurements made by simultaneous registering of the positions of each end of the rod in a frame of reference through which is moving yield a smaller length than you get in the rod's rest frame.

Comment: As an aside, I found Special Relativity much easier to grasp when I blotted out slogans such as "length contraction is physically real" and "moving clocks run slow", as well as all references to "observers". [It's not the observer that matters but the frame of reference.] Rant over.

Comment: @PhilipWood Thanks for your input. So by "physically real" it is meant that the measurement of the length is less in the frame of the observer at rest,  but there is no contraction of the material itself. Is that right?

Comment: @BobD I *wouldn't* say "there is no contraction of the material itself". The ruler is contracted in the frame in which it moves, so to say that the material isn't contracted would be, for me, close to a contradiction. What I'm saying is that relativistic length contraction is different from the contraction that you get by using length-wise compressive stress. The contractions are different phenomena. [Imperfect analogy: we can distinguish purely geometrically the contraction of a solid brought about by cooling it from the contraction brought about by end-to-end compressive stress.]

Comment: @PhilipWood OK. So in the rest frame we measure no change in the dimensions perpendicular to the velocity and a reduction in the dimension in the direction of the velocity. Can we draw any conclusion regarding a difference in the volume of the object as measured by the stationary observer vs the moving observer? Thanks for bearing with me on this.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sure we can. The object's volume is smaller in the frame in which it is moving than in the frame in which it is at rest. Have I fallen into a trap?

Comment: @PhilipWood If the object's volume is lesser when it is moving does it should mean that the object has either become denser or has lost some molecules

Comment: @ intuitive thinker I don't much like "*become* denser". It makes it seem as if, *even in its own rest frame* its density has increased. It downplays the key fact that we're measuring density in an odd way, because we're measuring the volume of the body while it's moving fast in our (lab) frame. In the lab frame the density is indeed greater for a body of fixed make-up. Although this is right, it's not telling us anything very useful about the body. [If we really wanted to know something useful about the body we'd divide our lab frame value by $\gamma$ to get the ordinary, rest frame density!]

Comment: @ intuitive thinker I have another dubious analogy. You measure the voltage across a current-carrying resistor, R, in a circuit with other resistors in series. You use an old-fashioned voltmeter which doesn't have a very high resistance. It registers the voltage across R that is correct *while it is doing the measuring*, but you are probably more interested in the voltage before you'd connected the meter, and will need to 'process' the reading (knowing the meter's own resistance) in order to find it.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake you made is that whilst spacetime is isotropic, relative velocity is not. By its very presence, it breaks the symmetry of spacetime. Hence length contraction can be asymmetric, and it is, it is in the direction of motion.

Comment: I don't know much about SR. But I do know that contraction does not occur perpendicular to the velocity. But if the contraction is physically real, why doesn't it result in extension or expansion perpendicular to the velocity, like what happens when an object is subjected to axial compressive loading?

Comment: @Bob D I think you're being misled by the phrase 'Physically real'. When people use this phrase about length contraction they don't mean that the contraction is identical in itself and in its consequences to the sort of contraction that you get when you put a rod under compressive stress along its long axis. They mean that perfectly rigorous length measurements made by *simultaneous* registering of the positions of each end of the rod in a frame of reference through which is moving yield a smaller length than you get in the rod's rest frame.

Comment: @BobD I think that the density of the body does not change, in the sense nothing really happens internally to the body. I think is what you mean, where the matters go, but it goes nowhere.

Comment: @Alchimists Hmm. So length contraction does not have any real physical consequences yet his partner, time dilation does (twin paradox)?

Comment: @BobD I am saying, in the time counterpart, that nothing happens to both the inner biological clocks of the twins. If one would have to calculate the density of a body, that would be higher if the body moves at relativistic speed. Right because the atoms of the body don't need to go somewhere at the side. It is purely geometric.

Comment: @Alchimsta If the returning twin is younger than his stay at home brother why isn’t he also shorter? Just kidding, no need to respond

Answer (score 1):

Nope, In which direction length contraction going to occur depends on the direction of the velocity of the object's frame relative to the rest frame (or observers frame).

In the simple instances, when the body moves along the positive $x$-axis, We get a length contraction given by
$$\Delta x'=\frac{\Delta x}{\gamma}$$
The anisotropy of the space is due to this direction of velocity.

If the velocity of the object would be in some other direction then of course the length contraction will occur differently.

Comment: I don't know much about SR. But I do know that contraction does not occur perpendicular to the velocity. But if the contraction is physically real, why doesn't it result in extension or expansion perpendicular to the velocity, like what happens when an object is subjected to axial compressive loading?

Comment: You can see the proof for length contraction. But physically, think of a train going on a track. If the expansion occurs perpendicular to the velocity, then the distance between the wheels would increase, and the train would go off the way for some observers, but this doesn't happen.

Comment: Not sure I follow you. It would not necessarily go "off the tracks". The tracks would constrain the expansion and be subject to stress.

Comment: @YoungKindaichi yeh I know that but why is it true? if only length is changing it means that volume is changing which should not be possible

Comment: @intuitive.thinker Why the change in volume is not possible?

Comment: right... it is possible

Comment: @YoungKindaichi I was thinking like "if no. of particles in the system is same after and before deformation then volume should also be same, but when u pointed out I again thought "um maybe there is a change in intermolecular distance"

Answer (score 1):

Length contraction is an effect caused by the relativity of simultaneity. It is a property of spacetime, not of objects as such.

Suppose you have two points in space that are at rest relative to each other a distance d apart. If you measure the distance in any other frame in which the points are moving along the line that joins them you get a shorter value for d. The reason is that in the other frame simultaneous measurements of the positions of the two points are actually measurements  *at two separate moments in the rest frame* . The position of the leading point is measured before the trailing point, which gives the trailing point a chance to move ahead before it is measured, so the recorded gap between the two points is shortened.

If you consider two additional points so that the four in total form a square, the two leading points (ie the leading corners of the square) are measured simultaneously in the moving frame, so the distance between them (ie at right angles to the direction of travel) is properly measured and doesn't become shortened.

So you see that the effect applies to the space itself, not just to objects.

As to how 'real' the effect is, you can find lots of writing by heavyweight physicists over the years that shows they clearly believe some kind of force acts on moving objects causing them to compress. I just can't buy into that. A thought experiment that makes the idea of 'real' compression hard to credit is simply to consider ten observers moving relative to you at ten different speeds. According to each of them you are currently compressed by ten different amounts all at once, which is clearly impossible.

Comment: Got it! thank you very much